# Where can I find a corpus of sentence with the resulting emotion in french?

Tags: corpora, french, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on a sentiment analysis program and I need to validate it using a corpus of sentence with the linked emotions.

I need to perform this task on a french corpus and I can't find any on the web, maybe someone has some links or know a corpus in french ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Kaggle there is a dataset with Tweets and polarity, I used this dataset.

There is the link:
https://www.kaggle.com/hbaflast/french-twitter-sentiment-analysis